# Spring MVC: how to download Excel from DB

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have a problem with Spring MVC and Excel. I store excel file in database as lob. Like this part of my entity database is PostgreSQL

```
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "Exel")
    private String exel;
```

Next I would like to get it from DB and user can download it from web page this is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExelTemplate.xls", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadExelTemplate(HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/x-msexcel");
        ExelDTO exel = service.getExel(new Long(1));
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(exel.getExel().getBytes());
        BufferedWriter outex = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.xls"));
        outex.write(exel.getExel());
        outex.close();
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(exel.getExel().getBytes());
        is.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

And I get not proper xls file with the bugs.
Please help me. What is wrong? When I get file from stream is the same effect.

Comment: Please could explain exactly what the problem is?

Comment: My problem is with that when i get the xls file on my hard disk it is the fail file and I have many strange thinks and I couldn't read it so it is not usefull. I think there is something with the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolve my problem, I change the type of data in hibernate entity to

```
@Lob
byte[] exelData;
```

and everything work well. When there was only text file there was no problem to mapping the @lob to the string but connected with ms office formats it fails. So I learned how to keep data file correctly.